# variable as Post_type in wp_query - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a question regarding **Wordpress** and selective post type selection.

I am building a template but I am trying to make a function with ACF that when someone makes a page they can select which post type they want to show on this page.

I made a variable with the following in it:

```
$p = the_field('post_typer');
```

This variable is getting his value when a user is making a page and selects which post type he wants to show.

```
 $p = the_field('post_typer');

    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  $p,
);
```

I am wondering why this is not working:

```
'post_type' =>  $p,
```

Please help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Maybe it will help if you add some detail of how you are using `$args` after it is defined, as well as the actual/expected results of the functions call(s).

Comment: The question is answered below in an answer. Why do you keep editing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of field you have, you should be doing get_field

```
$p = get_field('post_typer');

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  $p,
);
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Sorry not working. what i made in acf is a simple select tool with several values. every value stands for a custom post type.

Comment: Can you dump $p? var_dump(get_field('post_typer')) and paste it back

Comment: portfolio_cptstring(13) "portfolio_cpt"

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire code for the page? It should be working

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me:

```
        <?php 
        $tipo_post = get_field('tipo_de_post');
        $city_post = get_field('ciudad_npc');

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
              array( 
                'post_type' => $tipo_post, 
                'category_name' => $city_post, 
                'posts_per_page' => 700 
              )); 
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
              <li class="td-nombre text-left align-middle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('nombre'); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```